# Scaling any image keeping proportions and minimum width

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have image control that should display an image with dimensions previously unknown. It should fit in screen horizontally, and if it is too small - should be streched to half of the screen. Height should match, so proportions are kept.

What is xf analog of such css?

```
.img
{
   min-width: 50%;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about (ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Aspect/)

```
Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
```